# (ServiceNotFoundException) when calling the UpdateService operation through CircleCI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

As stated, running this through the aws-ecs orb for `circleci`. Error

```
An error occurred (ServiceNotFoundException) when calling the UpdateService operation:
```

I've already looked at https://discuss.circleci.com/t/ecs-deploy-script-error-service-not-found/4286 and [Ecs service doesn't update the task definition](https://serverfault.com/questions/821060/ecs-service-doesnt-update-the-task-definition) and updated the minimum health percentage. I've also got a 3 instance cluster, so I don't think it's a resource problem.

How do I diagnose this/what is going wrong?

One thing to note is that I see this in the cluster information

```
Active service count 0 Fargate, 1 EC2, 0 External
```

Is this happening because Active Service Count has 1 EC2 instance? What does that mean?

Answer (score 0):

In my case I 've written incorrect name of srvice in my pipeline .gitlab-ci.yml .